# How to replace values by NA in stack?

Tags: r, raster

Hello I am giving here a reproduc example. I have three rasters and I stacked them.
I want to replace any value above 50 by NA but I am getting an error:

```
     r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
     r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
     r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
     r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
     r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
     r2 <- setValues(r2, 1:ncell(r))
     St=stack(r,r1,r2)

     NAvalue(St) <- >50
   Error: unexpected '>=' in "NAvalue(St) =  >="
```

Any help?Thanks

Comment: How is a "value" defined in `St` ?

Comment: You say:  "I want to replace any value above 50"   Do you mean the values at `St@layers[[2]]@data@values` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> St[9,9]
     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
[1,]      89      89      89
> St[St >50] <- NA
> St[9,9]
     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
[1,]      NA      NA      NA
```